# How to allow child-element to expand height with vertical-align: super

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display mathematical equations that can be nested infinitely. But I am stuck on the correct styling of the exponents.
My current approach is as follows:

```
// HTML
<div class="power">
    3
    <div class="exponent">
      <span>2</span>
    </div>
  </div>

// CSS
.power {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.exponent {
  display: block;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.exponent span {
  vertical-align: super;
  height: 100%;
}
```

But this requires a height on the parent container (exponent) to be set in one way or another, to properly render the exponent above the base with `vertical-align: super;`.

I've also tried to achieve the same thing with `flexbox`, but basically ended up with the same issue of having to set the height manually.

I could obviously resort to setting the height via javascript, but is there a css-only-solution that automatically expands the height to accomodate the height of the child (exponent) and the height needed to lift it above the parent (base)?

Correctly displayed:

[image]

Wrongly displayed when exponent is nested with another euqation:

[image]

Comment: Have you ever heard of `sup` tag? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp. This might help you

Comment: Have you tried a `padding-bottom: 1em;` instead of the min-height?

Comment: No, that's a new one. Definitely better to use than `span` from a semantic standpoint, but unfortunately the link suggests that most browsers apply the same property `vertical-align` as a default I am already applying to set the styling. Thanks nonetheless!

Comment: I had the same issue (complex formulas, multiple base numbers, etc.) and I ended up using https://www.mathjax.org/ .

Comment: Just did now @CBroe and it works! Although I have no clue why that is. If you could shed some light on why it works and post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Give the `.exponent` element a background color, and then compare both versions in your browser - you’ll see that both achieve about the same _effective_ element height (which you need to increase the overall line height, because otherwise `vertical-align: super` just does not go as far up as you want it to.) The padding simply adds itself to the height the text content `2` by itself already provided, so this is a bit more “dynamic” than if you had to specify the whole height of the element, without knowing how high its content actually gets.

Comment: @CBroe Ahh okay, that makes sense. There is just so many little intricacies to css. Thanks for the explanation. Again, if you want the points just post it as a seperat 
post again and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this displayed as high as you want, the line height of the parent needs to be increased. Specifying a `min-height` for the `.exponent` achieved that already. But for that, you had to find some sort of “magic number”, and that doesn’t easily adapt dynamically to what height the actual text content of the element already provides.

Switching out the `min-height` for a `padding-bottom` can help make this a bit more dynamic, because that just adds spacing below the actual content, so the effective height of the element will be the height provided by the text content itself, plus the fixed padding value.